# Execute one batch file on several Windows clients with active directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

For installing programs using an exotic package manager, I would like to execute a .bat file (repeated at each logon until success) once on each computer connected to an active directory, with a specific user with enough privileges.

Let's go simple, let's say my command is:

```
rem Windows batch
net use s: \\myServer\exotic_share
c:\exotic\bin\install_stuffs.exe  s:\exotic\stuff_to_install
```

Is it possible to execute commands as privileged user without asking the user at logon?  What is the active directory stuff to use?

PS: I never used active directory before.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this problem? If so then I have some questions.... You are in an AD domain environment and you are a domain administrator? You just need to execute `install_stuffs.exe` onto each machine needed and when you say "*with a specific user with enough privileges*" you just mean that needs to be an account with enough privileges to install that and access the `\\myServer\exotic_share`, correct? Will the `install_stuffs.exe` process allow installing via UNC path rather than mapped drive to UNC path as well (i.e. `install_stuffs.exe \\myServer\exotic_share\~` )?

Comment: MUY - This question was bumbed by community so I looked at it. Can you clarify what this executable is doing so we can better understand the security context, etc. requirements for which permission may be applicable and so forth? Running a login script is possible a few ways and even executing as a PowerShell login script using an encrypted file method but I think before I get you something I may have that could potentially suffice, I need to hear back from your first with additional clarification and such. Anxious to help if you need it still and clarify so I understand 100% for sure. Time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to use group policy and a container in AD.

First, go into your `active directory Users and Computers Snapin` (Start > control panel > admin tools > Active directory users and computers) and creae a new Organisational unit (OU).  Place all of your users into the OU which you want the script to apply to.  You need to do this as you are next going to apply a policy to the container that these users are in.

Next, open the `Group Policy Management Console (GPMC)` and locate the OU which you are working with.  Right click it and choose the option "create a GPO and link it here"  This will create a `Group Policy Object (GPO)` which will be applied to all users and computers in your OU.

Right click the newly created policy and select Edit.  This will open a new window which will allow you to set settings for this policy.

Navigate in this window to `user settings > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts (Logon/Logoff) > Logon`  Within this area of GPMC, you can add scripts which will be run whenever a user (to whom this policy is applied) logs onto a PC.  You can add your batch files location here and then test.

Please note that the logon script will need to be placed in a location where everyone can access is in order for it to run.

Comment: Right script is executed whenever the user log in.  if I can read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753404.aspx , logon & logoff script are runned as user, startup & shutdown script are run as local system administrator.  So, I cannot do what I planned : I have to place either a startup either a shutdown script?

Comment: That should be ok.  The policy is in the same location, but you go through computer policies > policies.... and then set a startup script.. also, you put the computer accounts into the OU which you created at the beginning

Comment: Then you need to go back, re read my answer and do a bit of research on Technet regarding modifying your script to execute with higher priviledges - which is entirely possible.  This will give you everything you need